# button for add and remove component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to add new button which would add new tabs
I'm using [react-tabs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs)
which build tabs like this

```
<Tabs>
  <TabList>
    <Tab>Title 1</Tab>
    <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
  </TabList>
  <TabPanel>
    <h2>Any content 1</h2>
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel>
    <h2>Any content 2</h2>
  </TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

so I need two loop one for the tab and another one for tabpanel
like this

```
<Fragment>
  <Tabs>
    <TabList>
      {stats.map(({ figure = "", instructions = "" }, i) => {
        <Tab>
          <RichText
            tagName="h2"
            placeholder={__("Write Recipe title…")}
            value={figure}
            onChange={value => updateStatProp(i, "figure", value[0])}
          />
        </Tab>;
      })}
    </TabList>
    {stats.map(({ figure = "", instructions = "" }, i) => {
      <TabPanel>
        <RichText
          tagName="div"
          multiline="p"
          className="steps"
          placeholder={__("Write the instructions…")}
          value={instructions}
          onChange={value => updateStatProp(i, "instructions", value[0])}
        />
        <Button
          isLarge={true}
          onClick={() => {
            const newStats = _cloneDeep(stats);
            newStats.splice(i, 1);
            setAttributes({ stats: newStats });
          }}
        >
          <Dashicon icon="no-alt" />
        </Button>
      </TabPanel>;
    })}
  </Tabs>
  <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "8px 0" }}>
    {stats.length < 5 && (
      <Button
        isLarge={true}
        onClick={() => {
          const newStats = _cloneDeep(stats);
          newStats.push({ figure: "", instructions: "" });
          setAttributes({ stats: newStats });
        }}
      >
        Add new stat
      </Button>
    )}
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

The state is stats.
Each item in the stats array looks something like this { figure: '100k', instructions:'humans'}
The button "add new stat" just appends a new stat object to this array and calls setAttributes.
The remove button just removes the item at that index.

It doesn't give any errors but there isn't any tab added when I click on add new stat button
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the function given to `map`. Either return it or change the function body (`{}`) to parens (`()`) to make the return implicit:

```
<Fragment>
  <Tabs>
    <TabList>
      {stats.map(({ figure = "", instructions = "" }, i) => { // return statement
        return <Tab>
          <RichText
            tagName="h2"
            placeholder={__("Write Recipe title…")}
            value={figure}
            onChange={value => updateStatProp(i, "figure", value[0])}
          />
        </Tab>;
      })}
    </TabList>
    {stats.map(({ figure = "", instructions = "" }, i) => ( // implicit return
      <TabPanel>
        <RichText
          tagName="div"
          multiline="p"
          className="steps"
          placeholder={__("Write the instructions…")}
          value={instructions}
          onChange={value => updateStatProp(i, "instructions", value[0])}
        />
        <Button
          isLarge={true}
          onClick={() => {
            const newStats = _cloneDeep(stats);
            newStats.splice(i, 1);
            setAttributes({ stats: newStats });
          }}
        >
          <Dashicon icon="no-alt" />
        </Button>
      </TabPanel>;
    ))}
  </Tabs>
  <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "8px 0" }}>
    {stats.length < 5 && (
      <Button
        isLarge={true}
        onClick={() => {
          const newStats = _cloneDeep(stats);
          newStats.push({ figure: "", instructions: "" });
          setAttributes({ stats: newStats });
        }}
      >
        Add new stat
      </Button>
    )}
  </div>
</Fragment>
```